# редактирование дамп базы данных

Tags: база-данных, phpmyadmin

У меня есть тестовое задание. Мне нужно отредактировать дамп базу на сайте. После того как я загрузил исходник сайта и поставел его на open server, столкнулся с проблемой как открыть базу данных через phpmyadmin. (точнее какой файл вить там только один файл с расширением SQL  [в этом я пытаюсь разобраться](https://docviewer.yandex.ua/?url=ya-disk-public%3A%2F%2FaNDcqMrILv%2BDEQPSpHd3O5VhTVsC42EQamRBpdPWP40%3D&name=%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B5_%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_yantar_%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0.docx&c=5814a1d9b988))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Добрый день. Вам необходимо зайти в phpmyadmin, по дефолту(на open server) логин root и без пароля,далее я бы создал под проект новую базу данных "yantar-apart",и в ней после нажмите кнопку ИМПОРТ и выберите Ваш файл yantar-apart.sql